# On Bell inequality and bound entangled states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I have recently seen some presentation slides of [Michał Horodecki (slide number 77)](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/aubrun/cirm/horodecki.ppt) in which he discussed the following conjecture.

> Bound entangled states satisfy all Bell inequalities

The conjecture is not true for multi-partite systems, and the references are given in the talk itself. I believe by now, the bipartite case is also settled, one way or the other.

Bell theorem has some applications in computer science areas, like cryptography (non-local games). Is there some similar application of the (falsification of) the above conjecture? I mean, what are the interesting applications which can take place by disproving the above conjecture? Advanced thanks for any help/suggestions.

**To the Moderators:** I do not know, whether I should have asked this question in Physics or in Cstheory. Considering the fact that there can be physical applications also, I am posted the question here. Please suggest and/or take the required actions.

Comment: The original paper by Peres is [here](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/9807017)

Comment: @Trimok thanks a lot for the reference. i missed this paper. do you know the status of the bipartite case (of the above problem)? i could not find it out by tracking the citations of various papers on that problem.

Comment: I have used  these keywords for web research "Bound entangled states satisfy all Bell inequalities peres"

Comment: You could look at this paper: [All Bipartite Entangled States Display Some Hidden Nonlocality](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v100/i9/e090403). In it's discussion of previous work, it also has a number of references which I think address the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very recent paper: [Negativity and steering: a stronger Peres conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1767) makes a stronger version of Peres's original conjecture, which would appear to imply that the conjecture is still open.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity's sake, complimenting Peter's accepted answer, it appears that in a recent paper on the arXiv submitted on 5/01/14, the stronger Peres conjecture was shown to be false : [Steering bound entangled states: A counterexample to the stronger Peres conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0262)